# Find the function name associated with a number

Tags: vimscript, error

I'm trying to debug an error in a vim plugin. The only clue I'm getting regarding the location of the error is this message:

```
Error detected while processing function 190[2]..191[15]..218:
line   27:
<custom error message>
```

I've tried Googling an answer to this question, but it hasn't turned up anything. I know that:

- `[2]`, `[15]`, and `27` are line number offsets from the function definition, and
- `190`, `191`, and `218` point to functions.

I don't need help debugging the script, but I'd like to know how to find the names of these functions?  Is there a built-in Vim function to reveal the functions' number/name association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `fnum` to represent function number in this answer.

**Get numbered function definition**

```
:function {fnum}
```

It's documented at [:h numbered-function](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#numbered-function)

**Add breakpoint to numbered-function**

```
:breakadd func lnum fnum
```

Note that everytime you sourced a numbered function, a new numbered function is created.

**Add breakpoint to numbered-function without knowing the number**

It's the same job as get number of numbered-function from definition, it's dirty and crude, you properbally don't want to do it.

You can loop function number from 1 to a max number and compare result of `function {fnum}` and your current numbered function. There will be multiple results if numbered function is sourced multiple times.

**Set breakpoint to all numberd-funcitons**

```
:breakadd func lnum [0-9]\\\{1,\}
```

[:h :debug-name](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Adebug-name) use the same pattern with autocommand, it's documented at [:h file-pattern](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#file-pattern) .

**Update**

`:verbose function {fnum}` will also tell you where the function is defined (Thanks to Phi R).

Comment: Tpope’s scriptease is also good for this, providing a souped up Breakadd as well as other goodies

Comment: @D.BenKnoble It doesn't support numbered function.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: While it doesn't give you the name of the function, `:verbose function {42}` will show you where the function is defined.

Comment: @PhilR That's something i'm looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are profiling when the function is called, vim will print the lines of the function to a log file.

```
:profile foo.log
:profile func *
```

{do whatever causes the error}

```
:profile pause
:noautocmd qall!
```

Now, inspect `foo.log` for lines like `/FUNCTION\s\+190(/`.  The location (script/linenumber) where the function is defined will be printed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; however, I should've mentioned my error is thrown by an VimEnter autocommand, so I couldn't get profiling to work.