# How to read Vim stack trace?

Tags: vimscript

When debugging Vim plugin you may be confronted to error messages of the kind:

```
Error detected while processing function GrandFather[2]..Father[5]..Son
Line    6:
E484: Can't open file foo.txt
```

What does it means and how to identify the corresponding line of codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you have the following call stack:

```
Sun:6 E484: Can't open file foo.txt
Father:5
GrandFather:2
```

The `GrandFather` function calls the `Father` function at line 2.

Where line 1 is the first line of the `GrandFather` function right after the beginning of declaration of the function.

The `Father` function call the `Son` function at line 5.

The `Son` function fails at line 6 with the error `E484`.

You can get more information about error `E484` by using the command `:help E484`.

```
    0 function! Son(
    1    \ filename
    2    \ )
    3   " Read the file if possible
    4   echo "foo"
    5     \ . " bar"
 -> 6   call 
    7     \ readfile(a:filename)
    8 endfunction
     
    0 function! Father(
    1   \ filename
    2   \ )
    3   " Call Son:
    4   " That will read a file
 -> 5   call Son(a:filename)
    6 endfunction
     
    0 function! GrandFather(filename)
    1   " Call Father:
 -> 2   call Father(a:filename)
    3 endfunction
```

You can find where (filename, linenb) a function is defined using the Vim command: `:verbose function`.

e.g.:

```
:verbose function GrandFather
```

Remark: Method can be defined as anonymous function that are identified with a number. In such case you can use the `verbose function {number}` syntax:
e.g.:

```
:verbose function {234}
```

Here is an example of anonymous method:

```
let foo={}

function foo.bar()
  echom 'hello world'
  echoerr 42
endfunction

call foo.bar()
```

Here is the corresponding stack trace:

```
hello
     Error detected while processing function 239:
line    2:
42
```

Here is the result of `verbose function {239}

```
:Verbose function {239}
   function 239() dict
    Last set from ~/grr.vim line 3
1  ..echom.'hello world!'¶
2  ..echoerr.42¶
   endfunction
```

Remark: In stack trace your can encounter `<SNR>dd_` (e.g. `<SNR>42_`) prefix in the function name. These prefixes refer to script local function (e.g. `s:Father(filename)`) that are made global by Vim. The index (`42` in our example) is the rank of the script in the load process (the 42th line the result of `scriptname`). You can access the script with the `:scriptname` command (e.g. `:scriptname 42`)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I have corrected the typo.

Comment: @user202729, I can't reproduce the number function case. I'll be glad if you could help me to reproduce it.

Comment: This happens sometimes, the practical situation that I encounter it is vimtex methods. For a way to reproduce it, `let a={} | function a.abc() | echoerr 123 | endfunction | call a.abc()` (replace `|` with newline) -- note that `abc` is not displayed as the function name.

Comment: Thanks :-) I'll investigate ;-)

Comment: Looks like it's a numbered function. If the vim instance is still running https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20275/find-the-function-name-associated-with-a-number can be used to view the function source code, but otherwise there doesn't seem to be a good way. (I created https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/13722 for this)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll make some tests and update my solution.

Comment: The `:verbose` here was exactly what I needed - I was getting error messages that bore no relation to something in a plugin's git repo and this helped me get something more meaningful. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 1):

(shameless plug)

In [lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib) I provide a (i18n robust, on *nix at least) set of functions to decode stacktraces/callstacks. If your objective is to decode stacktraces displayed on errors, [I recommend to wrap it in a command](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Callstack.md#lhexceptionsay_what).

```
" .vimrc
" Parameter: number of errors to decode, default: "1"
command! -nargs=? WTF call lh#exception#say_what(<f-args>)
```

Comment: Thanks :-) I'll give it a try!

Comment: Hi @Luc, it seems to work very good thank you. Although to make it running on Windows with Vim 9.0 I had to replace `<q-args>` by `<f-args>`

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Thanks. I never remember which of the `<*-args>` is the correct one ^^'

Comment: The problem with `<q-args>` is that if there is no argument it become `""` and the code fails with `eval("")` you don't have the problem with `<f-args>`. Maybe could you also update GitHub. If you want I can propose a Pull Request if it helps.